# How to create a shortcut for special characters?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-word, gmail

I have to frequently use the Greek letter mu (μ) and punctuation mark Em Dash (—).

How can I easily add them through a keyboard shortcut? Is it possible to create a shortcut in Windows 10?

Comment: I've found a third-party application which might be helpful to you: https://thejournal.com/articles/2016/01/26/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-special-characters-in-windows-10.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad</kbd>/<kbd>A-F</kbd> to input UNICODE characters; First make sure the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> light on keyboard is on when using this method; To enable this method, first open elevated cmd:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→type `cmd`→<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then paste these commands:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method" /v EnableHexNumpad /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
shutdown /r /t 0
```

The first command adds a registry value that enables UNICODE input, the second command restarts your computer to make the registry value added by the first command to take effect.

To type UNICODE characters, first hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then press <kbd>+</kbd>, and press digits of the codepoint of the character one by one in the keyboard; To get codepoints, refer to this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

For example, Greek Small Letter Mu `μ` is located at codepoint `U+03BC`, to type it, use this method:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

For Em dash `—`, it is located at codepoint `U+2014`

Use this:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Word, you can find them in the symbols dialog and attach a keyboard shortcut. However, it will only apply in Word. You can get to the symbols dialog on the Insert tab. Also on that dialog is the ability to attach an AutoCorrect entry, which should apply in all Office programs.

You can also simply create an AutoText entry for the symbols. That will apply throughout Office.

Here is my article on Microsoft's site [Assigning Keyboard shortcuts in Microsoft Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).

Here are a couple of pages on using AutoCorrect. There is already a built-in entry for the m-dash and you can, on the Insert Symbol dialog tell Word to add an AutoCorrect entry for the symbol.

- [AutoText and AutoCorrect in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm) (my page)
- [Exploiting AutoCorrect](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/AutoCorrect.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill, Word MVP